# Can Hibernate criteria query in Grails be unit tested?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to write unit tests for a generic code base (uses Grails 2.5.1) without unit tests so that every part of code is tested. But I am having difficulties with testing criteria queries with Spock in all cases. Only `eq` can be tested - if `'in'` or `sqlRestriction` is used it cannot be tested.

I am stuck, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HibernateTestMixin uses Hibernate 4 and a H2 in-memory database. This makes it possible to use all GORM features also in Grails unit tests.

All features of GORM for Hibernate can be tested within a HibernateTestMixin unit test including:

- String-based HQL queries
- composite identifiers
- dirty checking methods
- any direct interaction with Hibernate

The implementation behind HibernateTestMixin takes care of setting up the Hibernate with the in-memory H2 database. It only configures the given domain classes for use in a unit test. The @Domain annotation is used to tell which domain classes should be configured.

Add following dependency to buildconfig

```
dependencies {
        test 'org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4'
    }
```

Add use the test mixins

```
@Domain(Person)
@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
```

Source: [grails 2.5.1 reference documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.1/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains)